# Technologies to use in a specific web project - The best place to ask this on stack exchange?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Working in the web industry for two year, I still do not find easy enough the first period of my projects.

As any developper, before starting a new web application there is a period of thinking about the architecture, the technologies to use, the approaches to avoid...

Can you please advice me in which site it will be approprite to give details about my project requirements and ask about the best technologies to use. I think in stackoverflow I should be asking questions about specific developping issues and provide with a code.

Any explanations are appreciated.

Thank you for your usual help

Comment: That sort of question isn't going to work anywhere on Stack Exchange. Recommendation questions don't fit the Q&A format.

Comment: A blanket "what is the best..." is normally not a good fit to any Stack Exchange site. And for most web projects, the answer would be - "whatever your team are comfortable with". You will need to give significant constraints in order for it to fit any site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no site on the SE network where this would be an appropriate question, for a number of reasons:

1. You're asking for product recommendations.  [That's not something we do here.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)
2. Asking which technology/language/tool is better is [also not appropriate](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/).
3. The question would be highly localized.  It would be specific to you and your situation, and not helpful to other people or future visitors.  This makes it "too localized".  SE exists to create a collection of knowledge that is useful to the internet at large; questions should be able to benefit other people in similar situations that will be able to find the question through web searches.

Comment: Thank you @Servy, I clearly start to understand what is the vision behind SE after reading the links you provided. Now I see that I should digg myself, and whenever I face an obstacle with a solution that can be useful to internet users at large, I can post it on a SE website.

Comment: +1 but not crazy about the TL description.  The user could specify the properties/constraints of the project thereby becoming general to everyone in that situation.  This is pretty much how every question works.

Comment: @djechlin In most situations in order to be able to really help someone provide this kind of advice you really need to know a lot of specifics about the project; usually so many specifics that the question loses is general applicability.