# In the last hours, why do new users with the association bonus think that Web Applications is about developing web apps rather than using them?

Tags: discussion, association-bonus

On [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) today, May 17, 2019 GMT-5, we've received several questions about developing web applications from new users with the association bonus (reputation = 101).

We have always had this kind of question, but from new users without the association bonus (reputation = 1), actually we have a specific close reason for questions about developing web apps, but usually we only get 1 or 2 questions daily. I'm amused that today in a short period of time we got "too many" (comparing with the usual amount that we get).

Is there any change on the way that Web Applications is being promoted across the Stack Exchange Network (SEN), or it's just that Web Applications is appearing on the search engine top results for these users because they visit other sites from SEN?

**Related**

- [What is the association bonus?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141648/289691) (For those who don't know what is the association bonus)
- [Recent proliferation of "How to code?" questions & SuperUser questions](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809) (h/t Glorfindel, a post from Meta Software Recommendations, from the "early days" of 2019)

---

For those who are looking advise regarding about how to / related to develop a web application, these questions might be helpful

- [Where do I ask a question about the best way to develop or code something?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291645/289691)  Spoiler alert this question is marked as duplicate of [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/289691)
- [Where I can ask for a review and feedback on my application?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181736/289691)
- [Technologies to use in a specific web project - The best place to ask this on stack exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179426/289691)

Comment: Is this someway related to "el día de Internet" (Internet Day) ? ref. http://www.diadeinternet.org/2019/

Comment: [Similar question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2809/23377) - but I don't think Web Applications is mentioned in the Ask a Question wizard on Stack Overflow. Or is it?

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh! Thank you. I didn't pay attention yet to the AQW. I will take a look to it a bit later.